Recent film about a guy who try to make her crush's divorce happen
I think the movie was from 2016 possibly 2017 and it's an American movie. 
I don't know any of the actors.
A guy comes to this bar all the time where the girl he loves works, but he can't get himself to tell her that he loves her. 
So the guy has been coming there for like a year or two and he sees that she gets married and that she want a divorce but the guy she is married to doesn't want to sign the papers. 
So the first guy make a plan to make him sign the papers so he gets another patron of the bar to help him to get the girl and the first guy pays him some money. And after some time he ask the other patron to kidnap him and the girl he loves who is the wife of the second guy, and he agrees to it for some payment so then the kidnapping happens. They end up at the first guys house. 
So then he gets the husband to go to the pool to get the suitcase where the "money" is but when he opens it he sees the divorce papers and he signs then and then he walks out the house where the cops are.
And the first guy asks the girl if she want to turn him in, but she doesn't want to and I think they fall in love. 

This is Get The Girl (2017)

Clarence is an awkward young man who is in love with a bartender named Alex. Despite visiting the bar multiple times, and an awkward encounter, Alex doesn’t really seem to notice him, partly due to preoccupation with her ongoing divorce proceedings. In order to get her attention, Clarence enlists the help of Patrick, a patron of another bar who seems to be able to get any woman he wants.
Patrick agrees to help him win over the girl. His plan is extreme – for $25,000, Patrick and others will kidnap Alex, and Clarence will rescue her. The experience will supposedly make Alex fall in love with Clarence.
The kidnappers go to Clarence’s residence, a large mansion. 
Wikipedia



A wealthy young man is conned into staging a fake kidnapping in order to be a hero and win the affection of a girl he's madly in love with. But when one of the hired kidnappers is accidentally killed during the charade, he's forced to actually save her life while not revealing that it's been a ruse all along.
IMDB


Thanks for the help... i tried to look for it for a very long time
